# Docker compose/nodejs: Restart required to connect after ECONNREFUSED

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, nestjs, typeorm

I have a docker-compose file. There is a `mysql` service and a `nodejs` service (Nestjs using TypeORM). Sometimes when I bring the stack up, the nestjs service tries to connect to the mysql service before it is ready, and gives me a ECONNREFUSED. I've set it up to retry connecting more or less indefinitely, but once mysql is up, it continues to give me the ECONNREFUSED error.

While it is retrying, and once mysql is up, I can connect to the mysql service using `nc mysql 3306`, confirming it indeed can. But for some reason I continue to get the ECONNREFUSED error. Once I restart the `nodejs` service it connects properly. The closest I've come to figuring out the problem is perhaps it has something to do with a Connection Pool that is created in the `typeorm` package. Any idea how I can deal with this?`

Comment: I can reproduce this with the standard TypoeORM module. It tries to reconnect 10 times but will always fail, even if the database has become accessible in the meantime. I think this is a problem with the @nestjs/typeorm package.

Comment: Thanks for checking that out. I'll try to investigate further

Comment: Hey guys any news? I'm facing the same issue, that'd be really helpful!